# I need a replacement heat sink thermistor for a MacPro1,1

Tags: cpu, temperature, water-cooling, sensors

I need a replacement heat sink thermistor for a MacPro1,1.

I pulled the 5160's and replaced them with 5350's (2.66/1066). I then did the BSEL and VID mods to get them working at 3.3/1333.

The heat was too much so I "rigged" a water cooling system. Broke both heat sink sensors trying to remove them, so now I need something to replace them with that the system will allow to boot. I get chimes (POST) but no further.

Was thinking a cheap 10k 2 wire thermistor.

Any ides?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get rid of the POST beeps - then you can try shorting the leads where the thermistors used to go with a small wire.

If you actually want temps, then maybe ebay? Possibly purchase an as-is model of the same card, swap - and sell card back to ebay as-is with explanation.